# how can i implement dynamic navigation/group header positioning in a winrt app?

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

I know the title is a little confusing, but the best way to describe what I'm after is by running the Weather metro app on the Consumer Preview; as you scroll horizontally, you'll note that the section headings kind of move around and stay on top of the relevant content, and then fade out as you cross over into a new section. (The main background for the first section also kind of does this)

My question is, how would I go about replicating this behavior in a WinRT app of my own? Are there any existing controls I can leverage or would I have to essentially rewrite it all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks just like a ScrollViewer - you would handle the [ViewChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.viewchanged.aspx) event and depending on the scroll offset - change the opacity of overlaid static TextBlocks and completely hide the ones that scroll once you cross specific tresholds. I don't think there is anything like that that does it, but I can build it.

Comment: hmm so I guess youd have to do some calculation as to what all the panels' offsets were, etc etc...okay! Too bad it isn't a standard WinRT control, cause it looks great